# Cassandra as a Windows Service won't start

Tags: windows, service, cassandra

I've installed Cassandra 3.0.20 and it works.

I need to run it as a Service so I performed the exact steps described here: https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-start-cassandra-as-service-in-windows-10-7-server.html

When trying to start the service I get "Error 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly".

What I also did was going to the registry and setting the `Jvm` parameter of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\cassandra\Parameters\Java` to `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`.

Oddly, today the service actually started up, but obviously it then crashed...now I'm getting the error 1067 again.

I also can't find anything helpful in the logs; Windows itself gives no other information than "terminated unexpectedly", there is nothing in the Cassandra logs and in the daemon log file (in `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Apache`)

Please note that prior to Cassandra 3, I've had a 2 version installed (DataStax Community Edition). The service worked like a charm with that one. I've had to remove/uninstall it completely as it set some environment variables (like `CASSANDRA_HOME`) which I had to remove from the registry in order to use Cassandra 3. I hope I caught everything, not sure whether some reminiscences of that could still be in the registry and influence the new service...

Any ideas what the problem might be / how to investigate this further?